# Is EventBus good for communication from RecyclerView adapter to a fragment which is using the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using a `RecyclerView` to show list of videos and on clicking any video the videoplayer starts the video and player has custom controls one which is next and previous and on clicking them RecyclerView gives the next or previous video. So here I am using EventBus for this communication between adapter and video player fragment.

Its works fine but I suspect there is a leakage in EventBus communication which for some heavy application may disrupt the flow.

Is there any alternative or a fix for such communication?

Comment: *I suspect there is a leakage in EventBus communication* - why?

Comment: I added log to check how many times the onEvent is called and found that after every complete cycle the the call is increased by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **EventBus** for decoupling your code is good. But for you case, it's a bit overkill. Your Fragment and RecyclerView adapter are a coupled code which are directly communicate each other and inside the same Activity (I assume you're using a single Activity that host the `RecyclerView` and the `Fragment`) so you don't need to use EventBus here.

theoretically, if you are sending a pojo (without any application context) there should'nt be any leakage.

Instead of using EventBus, you need to use **Callback / Listener**. You need to create a Listener in RecyclerView adapter and set the listener inside the Activity. Whenever you're clicking the video item, tell the listener to inform the Activity. When the listener get the message, open the Fragment with the selected video.

Comment: was trying something new to save the time but this leakage thing made me curious. I have used eventbus in many application but its the first time i got stuck with it